# Loop through a list of variables that contain spaces

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I'd like to loop through a list of variables (column names of a data frame) that contain spaces. The objective is, for each column, to filter the values in the column (remove the max value) and then, based on these filtered values, create a graph. I'm not sure how to do so. You'll see that I have used backquotes (`) for the variable names. It was easy to produce the graph (I had to use aes_string) but I have difficulties filtering the column.  Could someone kindly help me?

```
# data.frame template
df<- data.frame(a=c("type1", "type2", "type1", "type2", "type1", "type2"), b=c(30, 50, 40, 60, 70, 80), c=c(22, 33, 33, 55, 66, 77))
colnames(df) <- c("Type",  "How much?", "How old?")

# list with column names
list1 <- c("`How much?`", "`How old?`")

# function that only create the graph - this works fine
box <- function(data_f, var_name) {
  p <- ggplot(data_f, aes_string("Type", var_name)) + geom_boxplot()
  print(p)
}

for (i in list1) {box(df, i)}

# function that applies a filter and create the graph - this doesn not work
box <- function(data_f, var_name) {
  data_f <- data_f %>%
    filter(var_name < max(var_name))
  p <- ggplot(data_f, aes_string("Type", var_name)) + geom_boxplot()
  print(p)
}
```

Comment: *"loop through"* and *"filter"* are two different concepts. What do you intend the output to be, a vector of strings with zero spaces? vector with at least one space?

Comment: `grepl("\\s", colnames(df))` returns true/false for each column name, whether it contains at least one whitespace (e.g., space, tab). `grep("\\s", colnames(df))` will return zero or more integers indicating which of the names contain a space. `grep(..., value=TRUE)` returns a `character` vector (0 or more) with a space. You can use `grep(..., invert=TRUE)` to find the opposite, i.e., those with*out* whitespace.

Comment: Okay, so your problem is not how to find the spaces. You just want to produce boxplots that always exclude the max value, is that right?

Comment: This looks like you are trying to use `var_name` in `dplyr::filter` which *requires NSE*. That is, it is looking for a column *named* `"var_name"`. If you really need to use `dplyr::filter`, then you need to study [*Programming with dplyr*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). Or, you can use `data_f <- data_f[data_f[[var_name]] < max(data_f[[var_name]]),]` and avoid the standard/non-standard evaluation pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to use `var_name` in `dplyr::filter` which requires *NSE*. That is, it is looking for a column named `"var_name"`. If you really need to use `dplyr::filter`, then you need to study [*Programming with dplyr*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). Or, you can use base R and avoid the standard/non-standard evaluation pain.

```r
box <- function(data_f, var_name) {
  data_f <- data_f[data_f[[var_name]] < max(data_f[[var_name]]),]
  var_name_ticked <- paste0("`", var_name, "`")
  p <- ggplot(data_f, aes_string("Type", var_name_ticked)) + geom_boxplot()
  print(p)
}
for (i in grep("\\s", colnames(df), value=TRUE)) box(df, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand you just want to filter out the max value in each column, and after that plot the dataframe?
if so, this should work:

```
filtered_df <- lapply(df, function(x){
                x[-which.max(x)]
               }) %>% 
               do.call(what = "cbind") %>%
               as.data.frame()
```

This will produce a dataframe with the max value in each column- removed. plotting this will be like plotting any other dataframe.I also assumed you wanted to remove a single vallue from each column, if not - you can just pass a subset of the dataframe into lapply instead of the entire dataframe :  `df[,c('ColumnName1','ColumnName2,...)]` :

I will just add to why i think your idea did not work. It seems like the issue lies in your usage of the `filter` function inside a loop. each time your loop restarts, you filter using a different column, and then print the graph again, so every time you plot you get only partially what you want if at all.

What you should try to do in these types of situations is to first do your filtering and subsetting, and only then go for plotting, trying to plot and filter in the same loop is a common way to run into these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0):

`aes_string` has been deprecated, you can use non-standard evaluation to do this. As you are passing string column names use `sym` to convert string to symbol and evaluate it with `!!`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

box <- function(data_f, var_name) {
    col <- sym(var_name)
    data_f %>% filter(!!col < max(!!col)) %>% 
         ggplot() + aes(Type, !!col) + geom_boxplot()
}
```

now call this function in `lapply` :

```
all_plots <- lapply(grep('\\s', names(df), value = TRUE), box, data_f = df)
```

`all_plots` has list of plots, one for each column name.

```
all_plots[[1]]
```

[image]

Usually, it is better to have standard column names, one without spaces or special characters.